# Clarifications on definition of an indicator random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let's say I have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and a random variable defined on it, say $X$, which is equal to $0$ and $1$ with probabilities $p_0 > 0, p_1 > 0$ respectively, with $p_0 + p_1 = 1$.

I have two questions:

1. I know the notation for $X$ would be something like $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{B}) \to (\{0, 1\}, \mathcal{M})$  (i.e., a mapping over measurable spaces). Is $\mathcal{B}$ considered a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$?
2. What would the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ be? Is it $\sigma(\{\{0\}, \{1\}\})$?

These are questions that I can't seem to find answered in any textbook I own on measure theory, so I apologize for what may seem like a lack of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Balarka Sen for clarifications via chat.

When we say that $X$ is defined over the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, what we mean is that $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (\{0, 1\}, \sigma(\{\{0\}, \{1\}\}))$. Keep also in mind that the universal set that would be in $\sigma(\{\{0\}, \{1\}\})$ would be $\{0, 1\}$, as opposed to $\Omega$ like it usually is.